# Почему HttpGet запрос "ест" много трафика

Tags: android, java

Доброго времени суток. В приложении (Android) я пользуюсь API с сайта (получаю данные через url.openStream() из xml документа на сервере, использую XmlPullParser), но есть модули, для которых API не написан, потому приходится получать данные с помощью HttpGet запроса к серверу. Так вот, если делать запрос через HttpGet, то на ~1870 символов уходит ~70кб трафика, а если работать через url.openStream(), то на ~1950 символов уходит 10-12кб. Почему такая разница и как сократить "прожорство" HttpGet запроса?

Comment: А у Вас уже не хватает памяти?

Но по факту - думаю, что HttpGet получает всю страницу в строку. А  url.openStream позволяет вычитывать посимвольно, следовательно можно сэкономить память.

Comment: Как написал @falstaf используйте GZIP

Comment: @MrClon, не торопитесь, я тестировал))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Скорее всего, `url.openStream()` отсылает при запросе заголовок `Accept-Encoding: gzip[, deflate]`, вследствие чего бэкэнд выдаёт контент с компрессией.

Попробуйте отсылать этот заголовок и при запросе через `HttpGet`, и посмотрите, изменилось ли чего.

*UPDATED*:

Заглянул в документацию на [`HttpURLConnection`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html), и действительно, написано, что по умолчанию отсылается заголовок на запрос gzip-компрессии у сервера.

Comment: А ещё в подобных случаях можно просто дампнуть трафик и посмотреть что там пересылается. Например wireshark-ом. Или логи сервера посмотреть.

Comment: @falstaf, огромное спасибо, теперь 2 запроса вместе "кушают" чуть больше 6кб)) Теперь мини-чат в приложении не будет так много пожирать трафика) Еще раз огромнейшее спасибо!)

Comment: @PhoEn-X, рад, что смог помочь.